# Smoothly moving JLabel in a JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, animation, jlabel

I am trying to make a **Slot Machine** with a `JFrame`.

How do I move my `JLabel` with a **smooth** animation?
What I have tried is that I am increasing the delay in the loop with every round, but that is to slow.

It should move at the beginning very fast and getting at the end very slow.

Maybe anyone can help me to calculate the smooth better?

Here is my code of my `Animation` class extending `Thread`:

```
JLabel label; // thre Jlabel
int labelPosY, maxHeight; // label Y position and all Y positions in summary

Animate(JLabel label, int labelPosY, int maxHeight)
{
    this.label = label;
    this.labelPosY = labelPosY;
    this.maxHeight = maxHeight; // for example: -6500
}

public void run()
{
    int smooth; // smooth

    for (int i = this.maxHeight; i <= 0; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            smooth = 100 - (Math.abs(i) / (Math.abs(this.maxHeight) / 100)); // getting percentage of whole moving process

            Layout.setLabelPosY(this.label, this.labelPosY++); // changes Y position of JLabel

            Thread.sleep(smooth); // waits the always changing process (1ms - 100ms)
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbdYU.jpg)

Comment: I'd do this with custom painting rather than components. Keep a constant frame rate, but for earlier (faster) frames, move the image (shapes .. text) further each frame and perhaps draw 'ghosted' (translucent) images from where it was earlier. Further note that components can only be moved to integer positions, while `Graphics2D` allows us to draw shapes at positions set as double precision numbers. It's more flexible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Is there no way to slow down the Thred.sleep() ?

Comment: Yes, you can slow down the sleep period by increasing the wait time.  However, you can slow down the animation by taking 2, 3, 4, 5, or whatever number of sleep cycles to repaint the custom images.

Comment: Is it possible to use like for 90% of that 6500 loops 1ms delay and in the last 10% it starts slowing down smoothly (increase delay)?

Comment: You need a sleep delay of at least 5 milliseconds.  You don't need to draw 1,000 frames a second.  You can draw 40 frames a second (25 ms delay) and the animation will look smooth.  You don't change the frame rate.  Follow @Andrew Thompson's suggestion and move the image more in the beginning.  Besides, on a real slot machine, the animation of a reel stops abruptly on a symbol.

Comment: Thank you :)
And how do I stop the animation slowly?

Comment: Move the image 5 pixels / second for 2 seconds.  Move the image 4 pixels / second for 2 seconds.  Move the image 3 pixels / second for 2 seconds.  Move the image 2 pixels / second for 2 seconds.  Move the image 1 pixel / second for 3 seconds.

Comment: I'll try it thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to create a slot machine GUI in Java Swing.

1. Download slot machine images, like this one.  You can find many other images with Google.

[image: Slot machine images]

2. Read the image file from a properties folder in your Java project into a `BufferedImage`.
3. Divide the `BufferedImage` into individual `BufferedImage`s.  With this image, that would be 9 individual `BufferedImage`s.
4. Create a `BufferedImage` strip that's one image wide by nine images high.
5. Create the rotating image of a slot machine by animating the rotation of three or four copies of the `BufferedImage` strip.  You draw this image on a `JPanel` in the `JFrame`.
6. Keep track of the money spent and winnings on a control `JPanel` in the `JFrame`.  The spin `JButton` would also be placed on the control `JPanel`.